# WiX: Use Burn to install .NET then launch an MSI with its own WPF Embedded UI

Tags: wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper, burn

I have already made a MSI installer with WiX using a custom WPF UI with the EmbeddedUI element. It is similar to the sample found in src/DTF/Samples/EmbeddedUI.

I would now like to have a bootstrapper that checks if .NET 4 is installed and install it if it's not, and then launch my MSI.

It looks like Burn would override my WPF EmbeddedUI in order to chain the .NET 4 and MSI installations into a single installation with a single progress bar. I know that I could have a managed application to change the UI of Burn then pass parameters to my MSI but the problem is that I would like my UI to be in WPF which relies on .NET, and if the whole bootstrapper relies on .NET then the user couldn't even open the bootstrapper if he doesn't have it installed in the first place.

What I would like is the bootstrapper to install .NET if needed with a simple UI like Wixstdba, and then launch my MSI as it is, with its own WPF EmbeddedUI, without chaining it with the .NET installation. I don't mind that both installations would have their own progress bar, I would just like to be able to use my WPF EmbeddedUI for the installation of the main application.

Would that be possible. How? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your WiX bootstrapper to display the UI of your installer, set the [DisplayInternalUI](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_msipackage.htm) attrible of the MsiPackage to true. That solution does have the downside of displaying two UIs during install though.

You can also create a [managed bootstrapper application](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2011/10/28/introducing-managed-bootstrapper-applications.aspx) using WPF and .NET. Burn provides a way to basically bootstrap itself and install .NET before displaying your custom UI.

Comment: I have already tried DisplayInternalUI but it doesn't seem to work with an Embedded UI in the MSI, it only shows it if I have set an UIRef in it. (Ex: <UIRef Id="WixUI_Minimal" /> will work with DisplayInternalUI, but not my WPF UI).

Also, could you be a little more specific as to how a managed bootstrapper application could let me show my WPF UI only after having installed .NET?

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Sorry by "your custom UI" I meant a custom UI you create for Burn. It can be WPF and then you would specify the .NET prereq for the bootstrapper, as shown in the second link I included.

Comment: I see. I thought making my bootstrapper UI rely on .NET would make it impossible to launch if you don't have it installed already, but you can indeed set a .NET prerequisite before the custom boostrapper application containing the WPF UI is launched, that way it checks for .NET _then_ launch my UI, which is exactly what I wanted. Thanks for the answer!